# How do I create a list of a type that can hold anything available?

Tags: c#, types

I'm not sure how to put my problem into words, but I'll try my best by showing the code and what the app should do.

I'm creating an app that can create a video by creating a JSON file. This file will be opened with Camtasia.

I have this class:

```
class Track
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsLocked { get; set; } = false;
    public List<Media<Callout>> Content { get; set; }
}
```

And Media is in this file:

```
class Media<T>
{
}

class Callout
{
}
```

My problem is the List in the Track Class cannot only contain Media.
I'll need extra things such as Media or Media

What I want to do is let Content be a list of Media and Media can contain anything inside it.

I hope my question is clear, if not, I'm willing to provide additional information or code.

Comment: Would `List<Media<object>>` work?

Comment: The most "generic" type would be [System.Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: When I use it, I get this error: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'Media<Image>' to 'Media<object> This is the code I use to add it: track.Content.Add(new Media<Image>()); @dvo

Comment: That does not work either @paulsm4

Comment: Your problem is not creating a type that “can hold anything available”, it is that you don't know what types your list contains. Just because you don't know what types they are does not mean they can be “anything available”. You need to find out what types they actually are and create a list that can hold those types. The type system is there to do that for you, trying to circumvent it will not achieve what you are trying to do.

Comment: Actually @DourHighArch I need the List to be able to contain a couple of things, Media<Callout>, Media<Image>, Media<Text>, and so on. I just don't know how to achieve that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As paulsm4 mentioned in a comment, if you want truly *anything*, you could use a `List<Media<object>>`. The issue you were having with `track.Content.Add(new Media<Image>())` has to do with [covariance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/generics/covariance-and-contravariance), which is quite an advanced concept. The TL;DR is that if you change

```
class Media<T>
{
}
```

to

```
class Media<out T>
{
}
```

then it will work.

However, I don't believe that's the answer you really need. Surely there must be *some* constraint on the things you can have in a `Media` object. Therefore the solution would be to create an interface like `IMediaContent` and require all things that can be in Media to implement it. Then you would declare Media as

```
class Media<T> where T : IMediaContent
{
}
```

Edit: I just read your new comment about only requiring `Callout`, `Image`, `Text` and so on. I would then declare these classes like

```
class Callout : IMediaContent
{
}
```

Comment: I don't know how to implement that.

Comment: Which part specifically are you not sure about?

Comment: I don't how interfaces work, so I'm going to get into some research.

Comment: It's working fine now, Thank You so much for the answer :). I could of spent days researching.

Comment: Excellent answer!  ALSO: I was unfamiliar with the C# `out` keyword in the context of "covariance": https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/out-generic-modifier